# #memsql lowercase table names

Tags: lowercase, singlestore

we are evaluating memsql to port our mysql Web App to Memsql. 
Mainly our software is developed using .net on windows platform.
Last year we ported the Database layer to mysql on a linux server. First we had the problem that a select on a Table was case sensitive, because in .Net and windows it was not a problem to mix cases in Table names. This means if the table is named Test1 in Database, you were able to do: Select * from tesT1 and you received the result.
After running against mysql the Select failed.
Then we set parameter lowercase_table_names = 1 in my.cnf of mysql and the Select worked again.
Is there a similiar setting for memsql?

best regards
Kai

Answer (score 1):

Kai,

No, there's no similar setting in MemSQL.

If number of ways you spell your tables is not very large (e.g. it's either `table1` or `Table1`), then you can create views with different spellings you use, as in:

```
CREATE VIEW Table1 AS SELECT * FROM table1;
```

Selecting from such view is as fast as selecting from the table itself.